# Making a custom class's buttons trigger the parent class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I've got a `UIViewController` called "MainViewController" which uses a custom class 'CustomController' to control one of it's sub-views. The custom class instantiates `UIButton`s  in code. How would I get these buttons to trigger methods in the MainViewController?

Comment: I believe you can access parent class methods if they are declared in the header...

Comment: @CodaFi This is true, but then the class needs to know about the MainViewController and you have a tight coupling which is usually not desirable (especially if it is bidirectional). I would use delegation instead (check out my answer).

Comment: If I were him, I would use a class method anyways, seeing as it's cleaner and he could call an instance method from the class method if he needed to.  Besides, when his class is instantiated, it will automatically instantiate the super class, guaranteeing the success of his method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think delegation is the way to go there.

1. Define the protocol `CustomControllerDelegate` inside `CustomController.h` with a method like this for example:

   ```
   - (void) customControllerButtonPressed(id)sender; // BTW: you can use `CustomController` instead of `id` if you make a forward declaration for this class
   ```
2. Add a delegate property and synthesize it in the `.m` file

   ```
   @property (assign) id<CustomControllerDelgate> delegate;
   ```
3. Now when your button is pressed you simply call the delegate:

   ```
   [self.delegate customControllerButtonPressed:self];
   ```
4. In your `MainViewController` you make it conform to the specified protocol and set the CustomControllers delegate like so:

   ```
   CustomViewController *customVC = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
   customVC.delegate = self;
   ```
5. Now when the button is pressed, the `MainViewController`'s implementation of the specified method is called.